# How to disable multi-touch gestures 22.04

Tags: touchpad, multi-touch, gestures

Up until now, the 3 finger multi-touch gesture has just been an ongoing annoyance for me in Ubuntu. Recently, i started playing SimCity in Steam and if i accidentally do the 3 finger multi-gesture, it kicks me out of the game and i lose all progress. I tried the Disable Gestures 2021 Gnome Extension but it has no effect on my system in regards to multi-touch. Does anyone know if there is something more that i can do to disable this? I did look in xinput and it looks like my touchpad driver is xwayland-touch:16. Do you think the Gnome extension isn't working because I don't have the Synaptics driver?